# Android (Java) JSON gets sent to the sever but instead of "seeing" the data inside, it sees the toString of the Object

Tags: java, android, json, http-post

I have managed to send a JSONObject which contains another JSONOBject and a JSONArray to a sever which parses the request using php.

My problem is, that i recieve an error code from the sever which sends back error code '5' which in this project relates to "malformed JSON"

If this error occurs the data sent to the server is posted to a log file and my resulting log file is this information:

```
[Lorg.json.JSONObject;@b1fbc8c0
```

It seems to be the Objects to string, not the data itself.

This is my android code for sending to the sever, i followed several posts on this site and arrived at the following:

The pois list is correctly defined, that is not the problem i don't think.

public void uploadToServer(Vector pois)  {

```
    try {
        JSONObject auth = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject walk = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray points = new JSONArray();




        walk.put("walk name", "TEST NAME");
        walk.put("walk desc short", "TEST SHORT");
        walk.put("walk desc long", "TEST LONG");


        for(int i = 0; i < pois.size(); i ++){

            JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
            location.put("name", pois.get(i).getName());
            location.put("timestamp", 0);
            location.put("lattitude",pois.get(i).getLattitude());
            location.put("longitude",pois.get(i).getLongitude());
            location.put("Description",pois.get(i).getDescription());

            points.put(location);

        }

        auth.put("data", walk);

        walk.put("locations", points);

        auth.put("authorization","");
        auth.put("hash","3b6decebf0bab0e0a08c18a94849d6df1e536d65");
        auth.put("salt", "dave");

        UploadASyncTask upload = new UploadASyncTask();
        upload.execute(auth);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private class UploadASyncTask extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject...auth) {
        try{

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://project.chippy.ch/upload.php");

            List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", auth.toString()));

            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
            entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "WalkingTourCreator/1.0");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            String result = "";

            if(inputStream != null){
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

            }
            else{
                result = "Did not work!";

            }

            Log.d("RESULT", result);


        }catch(Exception e){

            Log.e("ERROR IN SEVER UPLOAD", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;


    }


}
```

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", auth[0].toString()));
```

because `JSONObject...auth`, where `auth` is an Array of JSONObject's